# Storing unsafe C derivative of temporary Python reference Cython

Tags: python, c, cython

Although I few similar questions already being asked, but I couldn't get head around on how to fix.

Basically I have this function:

Module one.pyx:

```
cdef char *isInData(data, dataLength):
    cdef char *ret = <char *>malloc(200)
    memset(ret, 0x00, 200)

    if (b"Hello" in data and b"World" in data):
        strcat(ret, b"Hello World!")

return ret
```

Module two.pyx:

```
import one
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc,realloc, free

cdef char *tempo():
    cdef char *str
    str = one.isInData(b"Hello what is up World", 23)

    # do some stuff
    free(str)
```

Issue occurs on line `str = one.isInData("Hello what is up World", 23)`, I am assuming that as soon as `isInData->ret` is assigned to `str`. `isInData->ret` is deleted which causes this issue. But annyone help me on how to fix this?

Comment: You're trying to `strcat` an uninitialized data buffer, and perform `in` tests between a `bytes` instance and a `str` instance.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I added `memset(ret, 0x00, 200)` after malloc, is that enough of a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import one
```

This line does a **Python** import of `one`. It doesn't know about any `cdef` functions defined in `one` (or even that `one` is a Cython module...). Therefore it assumes that `isInData` is a Python object that it can look up and that it'll be a callable returning another Python object.

`cdf char* str = some_python_function()` is unsafe because `str` points into the Python object. However the Python object is only a temporary and is most likely freed almost immediately.

What you mean is:

```
cimport one
```

which tells Cython that it's a Cython module that you're importing, and it should expect to find the declarations at compile-time. You'll probably need to write [a pxd file](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/pxd_files.html) to give the declarations.

---

I haven't looked in detail at the rest of your code so don't know if you are handling C strings right. But in general you may find it easier just to use Python strings rather than messing around with C string handling.